# Sistema Login - Py error

Tags: python, login

sou novo no mundo da tecnologia, trabalho mais com HTML e CSS e por gosto, estudo Python.
Estava eu tentando fazer uma verificação simples, mas que envolvesse funções. (para estudo)

Onde o erro me aparece e eu não consigo entender o problema

```
def login():
  print('Vamos realizar o login ...')
  user = str(input('Login: '))
  password = str(input('Password: '))
  if user == 'admin' and password == 123:
    print('Login feito com sucesso')
    menu()
  else:
    print('Login e senha incorretos, tente novamente')
    login()
      
    
def menu():
  print('Bem vindo(a) ao menu do sistema')
  opcao_inicial = str(input('[1] - Login\n[2] - Sair'))
  if (opcao_inicial == 1):
    print('Indo para o Login ...')
    login()
  elif (opcao_inicial == 2):
    print('Finalizando sistema')
  else:
    print('Valor invalido, escolha a opção novamente')
    menu()

print('Ola, seja bem vindo ao sistema')
login()
```

Onde eu coloco os dados corretamente mas ele so me passa pra condicionante que tem a senha ou login incorreto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note que na função `login()` você diz que password é uma string, mas no `if` você compara como um número:

```
password = str(input('Password: '))
if user == 'admin' and password == 123:
```

Para resolver o problema é só comparar a senha como string:

```
if user == 'admin' and password == '123':
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, me atentei tanto ao conceito, que sempre erro nesses erros bobos, que fazem total diferença, obrigado. Irei me atentar mais